# How do I control a process from a web app?

Tags: process

I want to interact with a running process (doing things like querying information and changing settings) through a web application.  How would I accomplish this?

Comment: The answer to this question depends very much on which technology you're using to write the web app, what OS and web server you're on, what process you want to interact with, etc. If you provide more information, you're much more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: You need to mention which OS this is and what programming language you'll be using.

Answer (score 0):

From a 1000 foot view, you can expose an entry point from the running application the web service can access.  In the case of ASP.NET/Windows Services (or any other running .net application on a windows machine) you can create a remotable object in the Windows Service which the ASP.NET web service can call and interface with.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this on my own I would expose an API for the application using sockets. If you wanted to geat into the real crazy stuff you could expose a SOAP interface with your application - then have a MUCH eaiser time intergrating the control of the application in C# or even PHP.

I could be more specific but need to know

- what OS you are running on
- what
  server side language you are using
  for your webpage
- do you have the
  ability to modify the application you
  want to control?